# Sending JSON to Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a push notification to an Android device using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

The JSON message **does not work, and I'm getting a 400 response**:

> {"to":"cXE06Grz67M:APA91bHoOc7pUPqKc9SMgCMKwH2s0r2zAyMac-LVjZVJiRLKSHCPVzi1K1tHmwq_Z35u8i32XL-cQKHGSWvzjD6ItvaMZh-LpRLHaz0iPQTMV-yQ6sqEHBjUvYkN3BDM4ftFowUs_L2p","data":"{\"PushMessage\":\"11\"}"}

**It is the "data" part that is causing a problem.**

The following - without the "data" part - **works and I'm getting a 200 response**:

> "to":"cXE06Grz67M:APA91bHoOc7pUPqKc9SMgCMKwH2s0r2zAyMac-LVjZVJiRLKSHCPVzi1K1tHmwq_Z35u8i32XL-cQKHGSWvzjD6ItvaMZh-LpRLHaz0iPQTMV-yQ6sqEHBjUvYkN3BDM4ftFowUs_L2p"}

What's wrong with the JSON format? And how can I fix it?

Specifically, the "data" part is generated from (server-side code is in Java):

```
HashMap<String, String> dataMessages = new HashMap<>();
dataMessages.put("PushMessage", Integer.toString(pushMessage));
...
Type stringStringMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String dataMessageString = gson.toJson(dataMessages, stringStringMap);
...
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
...
jsonObject.addProperty("data", dataMessageString);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may already recognize that the `data` part of the message isn't valid JSON.  The Gson conversion is adding extra quotes and back-slashes:

```
"data":"{\"PushMessage\":\"11\"}"
```

Should be:

```
"data": {"PushMessage":"11"}
```

I'm not very experienced with Gson.  The modifications shown below seem to produce the needed format.  There may be a better way.

```
HashMap<String, String> dataMessages = new HashMap<>();
dataMessages.put("PushMessage", Integer.toString(pushMessage));
...
Type stringStringMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
//String dataMessageString = gson.toJson(dataMessages, stringStringMap);

JsonElement dataElement = gson.toJsonTree(dataMessages, stringStringMap); //ADDED
...
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
...
jsonObject.add("data", dataElement); //CHANGED

Log.d(TAG, "gsonTest: " + jsonObject.toString()); //DEBUG
...
```